# No setter/field for found on class

Tags: java, android, firebase

Então pessoal, é uma pergunta meio batida eu sei, mas não consegui achar nenhuma solução aqui pro meu código. Eu preciso pegar as informações que estão dentro do nó 5883, mas aparentemente ele popula minha classe com as informações que estão por fora e acaba dando o erro `W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 5883 found on class com.mycomics.rest.model.ComicVineIssueModel` e não consigo fazer a comparação que preciso.

Firebase:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ComicVineModel:

```
public class ComicVineModel{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String api_detail_url;

    public ComicVineModel() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getApi_detail_url() {
        return api_detail_url;
    }

    public void setApi_detail_url(String api_detail_url) {
        this.api_detail_url = api_detail_url;
    }
}
```

ComicVineIssueModel

```
public class ComicVineIssueModel extends ComicVineModel{

private ComicVineModel volume;
private Integer issue_number;
private String store_date;
private String cover_date;
private ComicVineImageModel image;
private String description;

public ComicVineIssueModel() {
}

public Integer getIssue_number() {
    return issue_number;
}

public void setIssue_number(Integer issue_number) {
    this.issue_number = issue_number;
}

@Exclude
public ComicVineModel getVolume() {
    return volume;
}

public void setVolume(ComicVineModel volume) {
    this.volume = volume;
}

@Exclude
public String getStore_date() {
    return store_date;
}

public void setStore_date(String store_date) {
    this.store_date = store_date;
}

@Exclude
public ComicVineImageModel getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(ComicVineImageModel image) {
    this.image = image;
}

@Exclude
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Exclude
public String getCover_date() {
    return cover_date;
}

public void setCover_date(String cover_date) {
    this.cover_date = cover_date;
}
```

}

IssueAdapter (onde eu estou salvando e buscando os dados)

```
public class IssueAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IssueAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<ComicVineIssueModel> issue;
    private Context context;
    private boolean isExpand;
    private String textoFormatado = "";
    private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;
    private DatabaseReference firebase;
    private ChildEventListener childListenerEdicao;
    private ComicVineIssueModel issueModel = new ComicVineIssueModel();
    private ArrayList<ComicVineIssueModel> listIssue = new ArrayList();
    private String volume;
    private String idEdicao;

    public IssueAdapter(List<ComicVineIssueModel> issue, Context context, String volume) {
        this.issue = issue;
        this.context = context;
        this.volume = volume;

        setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemLista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_issue, parent, false);

        firebase = ConfigFirebase.getFirebase();

        return new MyViewHolder(itemLista);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        issueModel = issue.get(position);

       /*Código retirado para uma melhor visualização de onde pode estar o problema*/

        idEdicao = issueModel.getId().toString();

        holder.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(holder.check.getTag().equals("isChecked")){
                    holder.check.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.uncheck));
                    firebase.child(usuario()).child(volume).child(issue.get(position).getId().toString()).removeValue();
                    holder.check.setTag("uncheck");
                    Toast.makeText(context, issue.get(position).getName() + " deletado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    holder.check.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.check));
                    holder.check.setTag("isChecked");

                    issueModel.setIssue_number(issue.get(position).getIssue_number());
                    issueModel.setName(issue.get(position).getName());
                    issueModel.setId(issue.get(position).getId());

                    //salva a revista no Firebase no formato de: usuario - id da revista - id da edição - dados da revista
                    DatabaseReference firebaseSalvaRevista = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(usuario());
                    firebaseSalvaRevista.child(volume).child(issue.get(position).getId().toString()).setValue(issueModel);

                    Toast.makeText(context, issue.get(position).getName() + " está nos favoritos!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        firebase.child(usuario()).child(volume).child(idEdicao);
        recuperarDados(idEdicao, holder.check);
        firebase.addChildEventListener(childListenerEdicao);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return issue.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView ano;
        private TextView titulo;
        private TextView edicao;
        private ImageView capa;
        private ImageView check;
        private TextView informacoes;
        private ImageView seta;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ano = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idAnoEdicao);
            titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTitulo);
            capa = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idImagemEdicao);
            edicao = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idEdicao);
            informacoes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idInformacoes);
            seta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idSetaInformacoes);
            check = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idUncheck);
        }
    }

    public String usuario(){
        autenticacao = ConfigFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
        String usuario = autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail().toString();

        usuario = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(usuario);

        return usuario;
    }

    public void recuperarDados(final String id, final ImageView check){

        childListenerEdicao = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                listIssue.clear();

                for(DataSnapshot dados : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    issueModel = dados.getValue(ComicVineIssueModel.class);
                    listIssue.add(issueModel);
                    if(issueModel.getId().toString().equals(id)){
                        check.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.check));
                        check.setTag("isChecked");
                    }
                }
                IssueAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá, Acho que você tem um problema na forma com que salva os dados, mas para resolver o seu problema, você pode pegar os valores com um Map...

Comment: Cara, sou meio novo nisso e não sei usar bem o Map, teria algum exemplo pra me dar? Valeu!

Comment: Andei dando uma procurada na net e consegui resolver meu problema usando Map. Valeu pela dica!